# Passing inter node dependancy in nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way of passing dependencies to the nodejs modules? I am using gulp browserify and I have the following setup of my code.

***index.js***

```
var a = require('./a.js');
var b = require('./b.js');
b.test(a);
```

***a.js***

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log('Foo called!');
    }
}
```

***b.js***

```
module.exports = {
    bar: function() {
        console.log('Bar called!');
    },
    test: function(a) {
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: `passing dependencies` - What exactly you mean by that?

Comment: Is there any problem with what you have?

Comment: @thefourtheye I just want to use the the properties of the module "a" into the module "b". Though the code is working fine, but want to know what's the best practices for managing dependencies.

I am not sure what is the correct term for that, but I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Why don't you require `a` in `b`?

Comment: @thefourtheye can you please elaborate with some code examples? I am new to nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works because `b` doesn't directly depend on `a`.

If `b` *does* depend on `a` (for example you need to call `a.doSomething()` inside `b`), `b` should depend on `a`:

```
//a.js
exports.doSomething = function() {
  // do the thing!
}
```

-

```
// b.js
var a = require('./a');

a.doSomething();
```